# Magento 2: Way to Show Customer IP on "Customers Now Online"

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, filter

I've seen in Magento 2 documentation, it should show IP of "Now Online" customers. However I cannot find any setting related to enable this from admin, and there is no filter option for IP.

Is there a way to show IP of customer who are currently online in website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 native doesn't have feature to show customer IP who is online. There is other way, you have to create one module for display ip in back-end online customer grid. In that module create one di.xml file and use customer login event for get and save customer ip in 'customer_visitor' table. Create one column in customer online grid at back-end and display this ip from 'customer_visitor' table. You can get IP via below code.

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$obj = $om->get('Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress');
$ip =  $obj->getRemoteAddress();
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer from [Waqar Ali](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/78648/waqar-ali) is pretty much what you need.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/287427/106164

```
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;

class Index extends Action {
    private $remoteAddress;

    public function __construct(RemoteAddress $remoteAddress) {
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $ip = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
        echo "Visitor's IP = ".$ip;
    }
}
```