# Magento 2: How to get current IP Address?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, https

How could I get the current customer's IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){

    //ip from share internet
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

}elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){

    //ip pass from proxy
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

}else{

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

}

return $ip;
```

Comment: This is not the Magento way. I'd prefer the way [described by @waqar-ali](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/287427/31734)

Comment: Note that Magento overwrites global vars contents in some (if not all) contexts, so this solution may not work.

Answer (score 12):

**Try This**\

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;

class Index extends Action {
    private $remoteAddress;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
    ) {
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $ip = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
        echo "Visitor's IP = ".$ip;
    }
}
```

Source [Source](https://webkul.com/blog/get-ip-address-of-visitor-in-magento-2/)

Comment: How can I add this to the contact form in Magento2?

Comment: Most Probably you have to use plugin or preference to Contact form save class

Answer (score 0):

Use this block of code where you want to get ip:

```
function getUserIpAddr(){
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
            //ip from share internet
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
            //ip pass from proxy
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }else{
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
```

---

```
echo 'IP : '.getUserIpAddr();
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

For the Magento 2 way, you also need to add into the di.xml any headers you want to check or it isn't equivalent @Chriag. It will loop through each header and break if it finds one, and if not return remote_addr

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="alternativeHeaders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="http_client_ip" xsi:type="string">HTTP_CLIENT_IP</item>
            <item name="http_x_forwarded_for" xsi:type="string">HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;

class Index extends Action {
    private $remoteAddress;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
    ) {
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $ip = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
        echo "Visitor's IP = ".$ip;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any security issue in using this method ?

Comment: @AsharRiaz no more than any other method, it is just magento doing the same thing as the other methods, but just  through its framework and magento cleans it up a little more

Answer (score 0):

```
$objctManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$remote = $objctManager->get('Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress');
echo $remote->getRemoteAddress();
```